# login with Facebook in app using Sencha touch 2

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am newbie to Sencha touch 2. and tried the beginner guide of Sencha2. I am looking for a facebook login button in my app. I am not able to figure out how would I put the js part etc inside the sencha getting started app.

Can anyone give pointers?

I am also not sure how to add custom js code in framework.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [Jog with Friends example](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/example/jog-with-friends). I have to say, there are many parts of this example that I don't like or are not very Sencha-y (in my opinion), but I almost copy-pasted the facebook login part for my own proof-of-concept app.

To view the code, just download the sencha touch 2 code (which you probably already did), you can access the files in there.

Comment: could you implement this on localhost or did you have to upload your app to server?

Comment: I had it working fine on localhost (I abandoned the project by now) I'm afraid). I'm not sure if it was required or not, but I accessed it under http://tiggr.local:8081/ (and this is also the address I registered with facebook). Also, I do recall that at one point facebook didn't save my changes to my site-URL (it did in the interface but I couldn't use it). I had to create a new application in the facebook interface for it to work.